# Umbraco nodes and inodes

Tags: c#, inheritance, umbraco

I have a query about some code I am using:

```
List<INode> nodes = Node.GetCurrent().Parent.ChildrenAsList.FindAll(n => n.NodeTypeAlias == "Job")
foreach (Node job in nodes)
{
    MakeJobSummary(job, ref counter);
}
```

Is this going to create any problems as I am foreaching through the `INode` list but using them as `Node` (which inherits from `INode`)

I need to use the `Node` type as it has a few properties that are set from the values passed in through the `INode` and I can't see an easy way to get a list of Nodes from the parent object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this to ensure that the INode is in fact a Node.

```
List<INode> nodes = Node.GetCurrent().Parent.ChildrenAsList.FindAll(n => n.NodeTypeAlias == "Job")
foreach (var job in nodes)
{
    if (job is Node)
      MakeJobSummary((Node) job, ref counter);
}
```